# Syncing up Android devices to have the same exact time

Tags: android, time

In my app, I'm trying to have multiple Android devices perform an action at almost the same exact time. Since devices can have different system times, I was thinking I could have the devices connect to the same time server, and then just use that time to coordinate the actions. How exactly do I go about doing this? I can't override the system time, so how would I create a new clock?

Comment: What type of precision are you looking for?

Comment: Preferably around 50ms, but 100ms at most

Comment: Are you trying to synchronize them to a global clock (i.e., do this at exactly 12:00 according to atomic time) or just synchronize them to each other (i.e., do this at exactly 12:00 according to your system clock adjusting for each other's drift)?

Comment: Either way would be fine, as long as each of the devices perform the action at the same time as the others.

Comment: I'm not sure that your accuracy constraints are achievable since you have no control over things like process scheduling and native networking APIs Have a read on Network Time Protocol (NTP), because it sounds like that's what you're looking for, but you may not hit your target accuracy.